# How to connect without password in ssh2 nodejs

Tags: node.js

I want to connect ssh server from my ip with only username and host using node js. 
Here is my code.

```
 ssh.on('ready', function() {
             console.log("Server connected");
 }).connect({ 
            host: '111.222.333.444',
            username: 'user',
            port: '22'
});
```

But i am getting below error,

All configured authentication methods failed.

Comment: Why do you want to connect securely without... security?

Comment: actually i want this connection from my proxy server. Its has private key. So from proxy server i can connect without password.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ssh2](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2) module

```
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;

var conn = new Client();
conn.on('ready', function() 
{
    console.log("Server connected");
}).connect({
  host: '111.222.333.444',
  port: 22,
  username: 'user',
  privateKey: require('fs').readFileSync('/route/to/private/key')
});
```

Comment: there is no private key for this server.

Comment: btw, private key should be in the client side, here is a good link how to create key pair https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2